# When was the first time lower-class people had a reasonable chance of having a fair trial?

Tags: law

When was the first time in recorded history where the juridical system provided for protecting the rights of the general population, including the lower classes, so that a person of lower class could have a realistic chance to win a trial / legal battle, even against an opponent of higher social status.

To make this question answerable, I'll include a list of constraints.

- it doesn't have to be a perfectly equal or perfectly fair chance. Even today, even in the most egalitarian countries, someone who can afford a better lawyer or knows a lot of important people has at least somewhat increased chances. The point is having any realistic chance at all.
- if it was *only de jure*, but never practiced, it doesn't count. For it to count, there have to be at least some recorded cases of normal trials where it happened.
- Special occasions (the king on his birthday or on a national holiday providing justice for a poor beggar, or otherwise a highly notorious and very individual case) don't count if those people couldn't have had any chance at all at a regular trial.
- A formerly oppressed group gaining power in a revolution and therefore securing the rights doesn't count, unless they provide fair trial for the newly subjugated class. (For the sake of this question, the winners of the revolution no longer count as the lower class)

<sub>Note: if the underlying societies would prove to be so different that the very terms of "trial" , "law", or "lower class" would have vastly different meanings to decide a "winner", one could list other, possibly later cases from a different continent / completely different civilization.</sub>

Comment: Its seen as early as in Roman culture, those who were Roman citizens were given a fair trial, and could not be locked up without reasonable evidence and only Romans could be used as witnesses when a Roman was on trial.

Comment: Are you not restricting this to trials against the upper class? If not, then I don't think there's a "first time" to speak of. Why *wouldn't* members of the lower class have a reasonable chance of having a "fair trial" against *other members of the lower class*? I think that is generally true ever since the concept of trial and justice developed.

Comment: @Semaphore : The first paragraph mentions *"even against an opponent of higher social status."* I would be happy to reformulate the title and/or the opening paragraph if you think it is not clear enough and it could be improved.

Comment: @vsz Higher social status is a lot more expansive. For example, an elderly citizen has higher social status than a young person in Ancient China. But member of the actual nobility is far more powerful and privileged than the local elder. An apprentice is perhaps disadvantaged enough against his master in court; but he is typically far worse off to be up against a lord.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you mean by "realistic chance", I think a good argument can be made that it has not happened yet.

Comment: Well, Cicero prosecuted Verres, the Roman governor, on behalf of the people of Sicily - ie provincials - and won! Pretty impressive.

Comment: @TheHonRose that's the issue with this question; a single lawsuit won by the lower-class people does not amount to "a fair chance" (how many governors were guilt of the same things that Verres, but were impregnable? Was Verres just the exception -maybe, even, due to political influences-) Unless we have a list of all the lawsuits brought to bear, their merits (was the claimant right?) and the judements it is unanswerable. Also there is the issue of the meaning of "fair"; for ages killing a woman or a slave brought a less severe punishment that killing a man, and that was "fair".

Comment: @TheHonRose : I would accept the case of Verres as an answer if we can't find similar stories from earlier times, and if it was indeed a regular trial and not a show trial against Verres by his enemies. Of course, a good answer should point out the specifics of the time, and how easy or hard it was for a common man to at least get a trial (instead of being thrown out for not belonging). As the first point says, it doesn't have to be perfectly fair. The second point was only made to disqualify cases where the king or governor gave mercy to someone in a ritualistic manner on a special occasion.

Comment: This question is up to interpretation. Some suggested Romans had that, but Romans done it only with free citizens, and doesn't apply if you are a slave. But excluding slaves is an artificial line, wherever we can cut out the lower classes we do not take serious, and the rest will have equal rights and chances.

Comment: @vsz No, it wasn't a "show trial", Verres had gone further than most Roman governors in lining his own pockets in Sicily  whilst Cicero had gained a reputation for honesty and fair-dealing as quaestor there. Most Roman governors did similar and got off scot-free! I wouldn't want to post it as an answer, because tbh I'm sure others on here could offer a far fuller and more nuanced account - you could look at the Wikipedia article -https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero

Comment: Cicero also successfully defended Sextus Roscius against a charge of parricide  brought by Sulla's freedman - again a case of the small man against the powerful! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextus_Roscius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either never or in hunter gatherer days, depending on the meaning of your question.

The oldest recorded civilization is the Sumerians, which historians apparently claim practiced "fair trials".

http://www.angelfire.com/empire2/unkemptgoose/Sumerian.html

> Preserved clay tablets reveal that the Sumerians maintained courts of justice where people could expect a fair trial. One table recorded the oldest murder trial in history.Most of the food production and distribution was controlled through the temple. A noble class arose based on land ownership, control of trade, and manufacturing. Most trade and manufacturing was outside the temple’s control.